# asp.net aspx equivalent for .net core Environment.IsDevelopment

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I'm trying to skip some logic in an asp.net aspx page during my development / deubgging session. Does asp.net aspx have an established equivalent to asp.net core Environment.IsDevelopment?

For the time being I've just created a web.config appSetting "Environment" and have defined it as "development". Is this the correct way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. One often approach is to use a compiler directive. This has the advantage that such debug code WILL NOT be included in the resulting .dll compile, and can thus be useful to not include some code.

So this:

```
            {
                bool MyDebug = false;
    #if debug
                ' we are running in debug mode
                MyDebug = true;
    #else
                MyDebug = false;
    #endif
                Response.Write("Debug = " + MyDebug);

            }
```

Another way, is of course to simple go file->settings, and make your own setting and change it.

So project->my project settings, and then this:

[image]

Now, keep in mind, that those settings are created into a class at build time. So, you can't just change the setting, and without a re-build expect to see the change.

I OFTEN use the above for connection strings (as you can see in that screen cap).

But, if you using web publishing, and some transforms (to replace things like connection strings, then you have to use the configeration manager to get such values, and NOT this handy dandy base class.

So, in above to get a connection string, or MyDebug, you do this:

```
        Debug.Print("My Connection for Access db = " +
            Properties.Settings.Default.AccessDB);

        Debug.Print(" My debug setting = " +
            Properties.Settings.Default.MyDebug);
```

Output:

[image]

Of course the big issue with above, is the setting is not automatic, and if you change from debug to release, then the above setting does not automatic change like the conditional compile example.

I suppose I would put/create a global IsDebug function in my "general" global class where I put all my hodge podge bunch of handy and helper routines.

(in vb.net, that is a code module)

(in c#, that is a static class)

Comment: That's was really helpful. I think the settings you're describing is similar to the app settings which in doing right now. Problem is, when I push to different environments I need to remember to adjust that value. I think the compiler directives might be the way to go for me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes - probably best to have a global function in static class that returns true or false for mydebug - thus saving to write the if/then compiler directive over and over in code.